# How can I pull text from one word document to another?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to pull content from an excel spreadsheet as well as a word template into another template. I have the named ranges in the spreadsheet match their respective homes in the word templates tags, as well as the source documents tags matching the destination tags. Everything from the excel document successfully transfers over, but I am having trouble getting the word document text to transfer over. The start of the tags say whether the information is located in the excel doc or the word doc.

PC_ is for excel (that all works) PCM_ is for Word. The pc.word doc is the template that everything should transfer to. The message box that says "Yay" does pop up, so I know the Content Control is picking up the right type, but none of that text transfers over. Any ideas of what's wrong with the code here?

```
Sub PCExample()

Dim CS As Workbook
Dim wrd As Word.Application
Dim wrdm As Word.Application
Dim pc As Word.Document
Dim pcm As Word.Document
Dim CC As ContentControl
Dim CCTag As String
Dim CStxt As String
Dim PCMtxt As String

Set CS = ThisWorkbook

Set wrdm = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdm.DisplayAlerts = 0
wrdm.Visible = True
Set pcm = wrdm.Documents.Open("FilePath", ReadOnly:=True)

Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrd.DisplayAlerts = 0
wrd.Visible = True
Set pc = wrd.Documents.Open("FilePath", ReadOnly:=True)


For Each CC In pc.ContentControls
    On Error Resume Next
    CCTag = CC.Tag
    If CCTag <> "" And Left(CCTag, 3) = "PC_" Then
        CStxt = Range(CCTag)

            If CC.Type = wdContentControlRichText Or CC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
                CC.Range.Text = CStxt

            ElseIf CC.Type = wdContentControlComboBox Or CC.Type = wdContentControlDropdownList Then
                CC.DropdownListEntries.Item(CStxt).Select

            ElseIf CC.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
                    CC.Checked = False
                If CStxt = "True" Then
                    CC.Checked = True
                ElseIf CStxt = "False" Then
                    CC.Checked = False
                Else
                    CC.Checked = False
                End If
            End If
    ElseIf CCTag <> "" And Left(CCTag, 4) = "PCM_" Then
        PCMtxt = pcm.ContentControls(CCTag).Range.Text
            If CC.Type = wdContentControlRichText Or CC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
                MsgBox "Yay"
                CC.Range.Text = PCMtxt
            End If
    End If
Next CC
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next` and see what line if any is throwing an error.

Comment: @BigBen Oh okay, it was the PCMtxt = pcm.ContentControls(CCTag).Range.Text line. It's giving me an Invalid Parameter Error. I got this line from someone else's solution and they all said this worked.

Comment: To get the content control in the pcm document you need to use SelectContentControlByTag. See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytag

Comment: Thank you @TimothyRylatt that wokerd perfectly!